# Redirect Subdomain to Domain using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using Apache envvars for creating the MYDOMAIN and MYSUBDOMAIN variables where I define 'mydomain.com' and 'sub.mydomain.com'. I then use these variables in the apache sites-available conf files to deploy the website. The 'sub' subdomain resides in /var/www/html/sub/. I need to have a JavaScript function on the subdomain website check whether or not a particular file exists in /var/www/html and if so, redirect to that location (i.e. mydomain.com). I cannot hard-code any specific URL's - these will be dealt with strictly using apache envvars, so I need a solution that will work regardless what the domain/subdomain is.

For this purpose, I am using AJAX like this, if file.txt returns a success, redirect to the /index.php:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'HEAD',
                url: '/file.txt',
                success: function() {
                            setInterval(function () {
                                    location.replace("/index.php");
                            }, 5000);
                },
                error: function() {
                            console.log('404 Not Found');
                }
            });
});
```

Unfortunately the document root for the subdomain is /var/www/html/sub therefore /file.txt and /index.php are effectively being looked for in /var/www/html/sub/ - I need this to look for file.txt in /var/www/html/ and then redirect to /var/www/html/index.php.

I also tried using '../file.txt' and '../index.php' but this returns the same result (i.e. '404 Error' is logged because it is looking for what is essentially /var/www/html/sub/file.txt). Since I cannot access the apache envvars from JS (I think - would be a major security scare if I could!!) - what other options have I got?

Thanks!

Comment: don't understand why you don't do all this server side and redirect there

Comment: Because file.txt may or may not exist until a specific event happens on the server, which allows the user to use the subdomain mini-site until the full website is available.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hostFileUrl = function(fileName){
  return window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.hostname + "/" + fileName;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: hostFileUrl('file.txt'),
    success: function(){
      setInterval(function(){
        window.location.assign(hostFileUrl("index.php"));
      }, 5000);
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log('404 Not Found');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: The function hostFileUrl should help fix the issue with relative paths

Comment: This has potential, however, unfortunately window.location.hostname returns sub.domain.com - not domain.com as the JS is loaded on the sub.domain.com to detect if the file exists at domain.com